# Is $\{\operatorname{rect}(t-n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a complete orthonormal set in $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

In $L^2(\mathbb R)$, with the inner product
$$(f,g)=\int_\mathbb R f(t) \overline{g(t)}dt$$
the system of [rect functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) $\{\operatorname{rect}(t-n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal set. It is easily demonstrable. Is this system also complete in $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. Try to find a (nonzero) function, which is orthogonal to all your rectangle functions. For simplicity, you can find such $f$ which vanishes outside $(-1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that $\{\operatorname{rect}(t-n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ ca be complete in a space, different from $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Yes, they are complete in their closed span ;) This should be isometric to $\ell^2$. You should also check https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-Wavelet, which shows how they can be extended to a basis in $L^2$.